# Is there a way to load the install-interpreter.sh file in EMR in order to load 3rd party interpreters?

Tags: jdbc, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I have an Apache Zeppelin notebook running and I'm trying to load the jdbc and/or postgres interpreter to my notebook in order to write to a postgres DB from Zeppelin.

The main resource to load new interpreters [here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/manual/interpreterinstallation.html) tells me to run the code below to get other interpreters:

```
./bin/install-interpreter.sh --all
```

However, when I run this command in EMR terminal, I find that the EMR cluster does not come with an install-interpreter.sh executable file.

What is the recommended path?
1. Should I find the install-interpreter.sh file and load that to the EMR cluster under ./bin/?
2. Is there an EMR configuration on start time that would enable the install-interpreter.sh file?

Currently all tutorials and documentations assumes that you can run the install-interpreter.sh file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not run this code below in root (aka - ./ )

```
./bin/install-interpreter.sh --all
```

Instead in EMR, run the code above in Zeppelin, which in the EMR cluster, is in /usr/lib/zeppelin

Comment: small correction, . (dot) refers to current working directory(you can find the absolute path by running `pwd` using Shell interpreter(`%sh`)). As @BeerlsGood suggested, can try to run the script using the `/usr/lib/zeppelin/bin/install-interpreter.sh --all`